# Abnormal looping behaviour accessing list of objects in Python

Tags: python, list, class, object

Because I am new to Python, I'm having a hard time about the syntax. Consider that I have a `class A` that stores a list of objects of a `class B`. Each class has a value named `x`. At the end of the code, I iterate through a `list of A` comparing which `x` is bigger and printing on the console.

The code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x_a, listB=None):
        self.x = x_a
        if listB is None:
            listB = []
        self.listOfBs = listB

class B:
    def __init__(self, x_b, cp):
        self.x = x_b
        self.comparison = cp

ListB = []
for i in range(0,3): 
    x = B(i, None) 
    ListB.append(x)

ListA = []
for i in range(0,3):
    y = A(i,ListB) 
    ListA.append(y)

for a in ListA:
    for b in a.listOfBs:
        if a.x > b.x:
            b.comparison = 'A IS BIGGER'

        else:
            b.comparison = 'A IS NOT BIGGER'

for a in ListA:
    for b in a.listOfBs:
        print(a.x, b.x, b.comparison)
```

The output I'm receiving is:

```
(0, 0, 'A IS BIGGER')
(0, 1, 'A IS BIGGER')
(0, 2, 'A IS NOT BIGGER')
(1, 0, 'A IS BIGGER')
(1, 1, 'A IS BIGGER')
(1, 2, 'A IS NOT BIGGER')
(2, 0, 'A IS BIGGER')
(2, 1, 'A IS BIGGER')
(2, 2, 'A IS NOT BIGGER')
```

Which it's not quite expected.

**EDIT** Output expected is:

```
(0, 0, 'A IS BIGGER')
(0, 1, 'A IS NOT BIGGER')
(0, 2, 'A IS NOT BIGGER')
(1, 0, 'A IS BIGGER')
(1, 1, 'A IS NOT BIGGER')
(1, 2, 'A IS NOT BIGGER')
(2, 0, 'A IS BIGGER')
(2, 1, 'A IS BIGGER')
(2, 2, 'A IS NOT BIGGER')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: your code only has two lists, try seeing in [pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com) that might explain why it's happening like it is. Otherwise please specify what you expect it to do instead because idk which part you aren't understanding

Comment: Hello. For each object inside ListA, I have a List of B. The output I was expecting for is, for example: (1, 0 , 'A IS BIGGER'') because 1 > 0. I am comparing the x from each of the A objects of my list ListA with the x of all the B objects of the list I have inside of it.

Comment: "For each object inside ListA, I have a List of B" **no all the lists of B point to the same list, there is only one.**  Python tutor will show this although there are enough other things that it gets pretty cluttered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your class A objects have a variable `self.listOfBs` that points to the same exact list... with the same three B objects.  You don't have 3 B objects per A object; you have 3 B objects total.  And each of those B objects has a `b.comparison` variable.

In your comparison loops, when you assign a value to `b.comparison` you are making assignments to the same b object you did the last time through the loop, overwriting the previous value.

A simple fix is to create a deep-copy of the list in the class A init function.  Each A object will have its own list of 3 NEW B objects.  Now your comparison loops will be making assignments to the A object's unique list of B objects instead.

```
import copy

class A:
    def __init__(self, x_a, listB=None):
        self.x = x_a
        if listB is None:
            self.listOfBs = []
        else:
            self.listOfBs = copy.deepcopy(listB)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you set `b.comparison`, you overwrite the previous value of `b.comparison`. If you want to store multiple comparisons in one attribute, consider another datatype, like a `dict`ionary.

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, x_b, cp):
        self.x = x_b
        if cp is None:
            cp = {}
        self.comparison = cp

for a in ListA:
    for b in a.listOfBs:
        if a.x > b.x:
            # Think of it as "b's comparison _with_ a"
            b.comparison[a] = 'A IS BIGGER'
        else:
            b.comparison[a] = 'A IS NOT BIGGER'

for a in ListA:
    for b in a.listOfBs:
        print(a.x, b.x, b.comparison[a])
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you but since this is a simplication of my real problem, I will need the actual implementation of the class A.